# "Global" WPF ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have different `UserControls` which each have different `ViewModels`. But I have some "Global" variables like Background-color or some arrays with data, which every ViewModel needs, in the `MainViewModel`.

How do I tell my other `ViewModels` which Background-Color the user has set in the `MainView`?

Comment: The background color stuff is better done with theming. It doesn't belong in a viewmodel. If there's anything else that does belong in the viewmodel realm and really needs to be shared, you might consider adding a [singleton viewmodel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which is in charge of that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have styling informations in your viewmodels in the first place.

But if you need some shared properties, I suggest using the Service pattern; it consist in creating a Service class, which is roughly equivalent to a singleton, that you inject in viewmodels that need it.

See [this StackOverflow question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351117/c-sharp-mvvm-where-does-the-service-layer-sit) for more information, or simply search for "Service Layer" and "Dependency Injection".

Comment: i will try that out, thanks. unfortunately I now have less than 15 rep points so I cant upvote, since every time I post a question I get exactly one downvote; I never understand why...

Comment: @MaxR. probably because there is no code shown. Some people here think that no code = bad question, but I see why your question didn't need code.